# How can I create relation to yii2-user?

Tags: php, yii2

I have for example 2 Entities: `User` and `Post`.

I want to have OneToMany relation( one User has many Posts) but I don't know how to do that. I've used yii2-user module to have authorization, registration etc. That works fine but now I faced in question how to create that relation.

I've created that in my Post model:

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(),['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
```

but now I can't fetch posts from user like `$user->getPosts()`.

Comment: for get the post of a user you should extend  you User model ad a realtion one to many for get the related  post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your User model  you should add  a hasMany relation 
and if you want preserve  your Model based on 3th party extension  a common practice is based on extend  the base class with  a your property class  and add  all the method you need

```
class MyUser extends User
{
   public function getPost() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);

   }
....
```

and you can refer  to

```
$myUserModel= MyUser::findOne($id)->with('posts');

$myUsermModel->post;
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: I know how to create simple relation but I've used yii2-user extension. And how I can handle with it?

Comment: a common practice is based on creation of and extended  class  starting from  your User extension and add  all the new method you need .. obviously when you need  you must refer to your extended  class ... hope this is clear ..

Answer (score 2):

add a one to many relation in your user model

```
public function getPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::className(),['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

then for each user $model you get all posts using

```
$posts = $model->posts;
```

Comment: I know how to create simple relation but I've used yii2-user extension. And how I can handle with it?

Comment: the relation is between 2 tables, represented by models. define these relations in the respective models and it should work fine. the user model in your extensions and the post model

Comment: if you dont want to go this way you can use active record `$posts = Post::findAllByAttributes(['user_id' => $id])`

Answer (score 1):

In the user model you can write this:

```
public function getPosts()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Post::className(),['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And you get the post like this:

```
$model = User::findOne($id)->with('posts');
```

Comment: I know how to create simple relation but I've used yii2-user extension. And how I can handle with it?